# Why does my laptop give a loud beep everytime I unplug from AC power?

Tags: power-management

This used to happen only if I do it before Ubuntu was fully loaded or if it was just waking from a suspend, but now it started happening always. My laptop is Acer Aspire 5740. Can the OS suppress this beep?

Comment: If you remember or if you have windows installed does this happen there? (When I Google the laptop I noticed that it came with windows 7 64-bit.)
What Ubuntu version do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the PC speaker driver type `sudo rmmod pcspkr` to add it again `sudo modprobe pcspkr`.

In Addition try System -> Preferences -> Sound and select the System Beep tab. Then de-select the system beep.

Comment: Not related to OP's question, but I don't see a System Beep tab under Sound on 10.10. What version are you using?

Comment: Thanks, muting 'Beep' from alsamixer did the trick for me.

Comment: I’d like to enable the warning beep when power is unplugged, but `sudo modprobe pcspkr` didn't do it for me. Ubuntu 12.04